# How do you find the page views by URL of a GA4 property?

Tags: google-analytics-4

How do you find the page views by URL of a GA4 property?

When checking the Engagement Reports, it shows 0 views which I know is inaccurate because we are getting people to sign up using a link on that page.  I plugged in the URL right above the reports at the bottom.